# Flatlist - Each row's component lifecycle getting called again while scroll

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I have created chat in a `Flatlist`. Each `row` is created as `component` and each component has `willMount` and `didMount`.

At first time, when flatlist loads, I have called **service** in `didMount` in each row to update the view after message displayed. I thought this service will be called only once after `render`.

**But the problem is :**
While scrolling, Flatlist `unmount` the rows which is not in **viewport**.  When row is `mounted`, state value sets to initial and again lifecyle starts.

So I could not able to stop the service call after first time.

**How do I stop the service call once flatlist rendered for the first time**? Is there any way to reduce the call or any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

`Flatlist` doesn't render all rows at the same time. It recycles views to rows that should be visible on screen. It's fast and saves memory.

You could use `ScrollView`, it will render all rows at once.

Or you could keep using `Flatlist`, and move `didMount` in the rows to their parent.

See more comparisons between `Flatlist` and `ScrollView` at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html